# editing and saving a particular values in the table using grails

Tags: grails

i have two classes User and UserGroup

```
class User{ 

  String userId
  String userName
  UserGroup usergroups
  static hasMany={usergroups:UserGroup}
  static belongsTo=UserGroup
}

class UserGroup{
  String gid
  static hasMany={users:User}
}
```

Now,i want to take only usergroups in seperate template modify value and save it back to the database.In my User Controller I wrote

```
def savegroup = {
    def userInstance = User.get(params.id)
    if (userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
      redirect(action: "show")
    }
}
```

but its showing an error.please tell me what do i need to write in my controller??

Comment: savegroup isn't saving a group.  You're getting and saving a userInstance, and you're not even modifying the userInstance.  Also, without telling us what error you get, we can't help you.

Comment: Error 500: Executing action [savegroup] of controller [app.UserController] caused exception: Cannot invoke method save() on null object

Comment: this is the error i got.please tell me what do i need to change instead of userInstance??

Answer (score 0):

you want to modify a particular UserGroup object. first of all you have to assure that your passed params.id is the id of your user group to change. then you have to fetch the right user group object and not a user instance!

```
def savegroup = {
    // make sure your're getting the right id!
    def userGroup= UserGroup.get(params.id)
    // check whether the userGroup is not null
    if (userGroup.save(flush: true)) {
      redirect(action: "show")
    } else {
       // log msg
    }
}
```

Comment: thank tou @hitty5,i'm selecting  multiple values.can i use getAll() method?

Comment: you have to pass the selected ids to your controller. there you can call e.g. UserGroup.getAll(params.list['selectedIds'])